# Uploading a directory full of files in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I can't find this topic in the documentation.  I'm trying to upload a folder of files to GitLab - i.e. the file containing the entire webpage, (HTML files, assets, JS, etc.)  In other words, I want to upload my entire repo to GitLab.

But, I only see the option to upload a single file at a time:

[image]

How can I upload a folder of files?

Answer (score 1):

Folder upload is not supported. There is a [request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14207) to allow uploading multiple files, however it is from 2016 and as of 2024 it is still marked as open.

You could clone the project locally (blue button) creating a local repository and move/copy the folder to your local git-repository.
Then you just `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` everything.

Step by step explanation:

- Stage everything in git repo: `git add -A` The parameter "`-A`" stands for "all".  It will add every file and folder (apart for empty folders) that are in the repository to the commit.
- `git commit -m 'your message'` will commit all your files/changes locally.
- `git push` will upload your commits so that you can see them on your GitLab page.

Comment: Thanks - is there documentation for how to do this?  It seems silly Gitlab won't let you upload a folder.. is the git add, git commit, etc. you referenced above in command line?  I'd like to find a way to do this without using command line since this is a shared Gitlab project with other people without command line access.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is command line, if you use a VS Code or another IDE it might be integrated. You don't need to worry about the others not having this access. What you are doing is an only needed once. Later on everyone can use the web-editor within GitLab, so they won't need command line access.

Comment: If the proposed solution did work, please mark it accordingly.